# Raspberry Pi, DD-WRT and dynamic IP (No-IP) setup

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, dd-wrt, dynamic-ip

My idea is to get the access to my raspberry server (ssh, webmin, deluge web)  from the Internet.

I add the dynamic DNS service to my dd-wrt router and I can access it (web ui) from Internet.

I install the no-ip on my raspberry and run it.

But I cannot access to ssh, webmin and deluge web using my host name provided by No-IP.

So, my questions is:

1. If I already add no-ip dns to my router, do I need to add it to my raspberry too? Or it can be managed by router? If yes how?
2. How to configure dynamic dns with no-ip on raspberry?
3. When I enable web ui on my router, there is some basic security settings that I need to check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your raspberry is inside the LAN of your dd-wrt broadband router, what you need is adding port forward from the WAN side to your Pi. Only one "machine" need to update no-ip.org for updating the dynamic DNS provider.

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly in dd-wrt I can find this option? There is no configuration at the raspberry level at all?